# Overwriting files found by find?

Tags: find, filenames

I have a list of files

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 t t 24813 Oct 23  2002 fig8_21.gif
-rw-rw-r-- 1 t t  2259 Oct 23  2002 fig8_21t.gif
-rw-rw-r-- 1 t t 35331 Oct 23  2002 fig8_23.gif
-rw-rw-r-- 1 t t  2610 Oct 23  2002 fig8_23t.gif
-rw-rw-r-- 1 t t 19970 Oct 23  2002 fig8_24.gif
-rw-rw-r-- 1 t t  2019 Oct 23  2002 fig8_24t.gif
-rw-rw-r-- 1 t t 54623 Oct 23  2002 fig8_3.gif
-rw-rw-r-- 1 t t  3657 Oct 23  2002 fig8_3t.gif
-rw-rw-r-- 1 t t 35861 Oct 23  2002 fig8_4.gif
-rw-rw-r-- 1 t t  2344 Oct 23  2002 fig8_4t.gif
```

I want to overwrite `<...>t.gif` with `<...>.gif` e.g. copy `fig8_4.gif` to overwrite `fig8_4t.gif`.

I first find those `<...>t.gif` files by `find .  -regex ".*t\.gif"`. Then I want to use `basename` to strip the filenames, but why do I have the following warnings?

```
$ find .  -regex ".*t\.gif" -execdir basename {} \;  
find: The relative path `~/program_files/internet/SSH_tunneling/' is included in the PATH environment variable, which is insecure in combination with the -execdir action of find.  Please remove that entry from $PATH

$ find .  -regex ".*t\.gif" | xargs basename 
basename: extra operand ‘./f10_1t.gif’
```

How shall I continue to finish my task?

Is it possible not using `find`?

Comment: can someone tell me why my usages of find have the errors?

Comment: For find more about errors, see: [Why using the '-execdir' action is insecure for directory which is in the PATH?](http://askubuntu.com/q/621132/78223) at Ubuntu SE

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's possible.  One way to do it might look like this:

```bash
cd /den/of/gifs && \
for f in ./*t.gif; do
    mv -- "${f%%t.gif}.gif" "$f"
done
```

The `${var%%pattern}` thing is standard/POSIX `sh` syntax for removing the longest string that matches *pattern* from the end of `$var`.

Comment: `${...%%...}` is POSIX one.

Comment: I suppose you are replacing `<...>.gif` files with `<...>t.gif` files, whereas the OP wants the opposite.

Comment: You only need a single `%`

Answer (score 2):

To make it even more compact and faster, you could use `parallel`:

```
parallel mv {} {.}t.gif  :::: <(find . -regex '.+[0-9].gif')
```

The expression after `::::` provides arguments for `parallel`. These arguments are then used using `{}`. The `{.}` represents the argument without the file-extension. So, in our case `{}` will be the file names of files without the `t` in them, e.g. `fig8_4.gif`. `{.}` would then be `fig8_4`.

Comment: What you save in wall-clock time by running things in parallel you lose in cpu time as `parallel` has a misfeature in that is spawns a shell (`$SHELL`, not `sh`) to run those commands. Also note that it won't work if the file names contain newline characters, or possibly other characters depending on you `$SHELL` (for instance, it fails to escape `=` globs in `zsh` and `^` in the Bourne shell). You may want to run it with SHELL=/bin/sh (or SHELL=/usr/xpg4/bin/sh on Solaris 10 and earlier) to avoid surprises.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stay with `find` and `basename`, this should work:

```
find . -name "*.gif" ! -name "*t.gif" -execdir sh -c '
  cp -- "$0" "$(basename "$0" .gif)t.gif"' {} \;
```

This is performance- and resource-wise not the best option.

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas Thanks for improving! Just to note: this isn't working on my busybox.

Comment: No, `busybox find` doesn't have `-execdir`, nor does it have standard predicates like `-ok` or `-nouser` (so could be considered off-topic here). The OP did use `-execdir`. With `-exec`, the answer is wrong though, you'd need to use `$(dirname...)/$(basename...)` or use the shell's `${var%.gif}` form.

Comment: I see your point. Well, it's not clear if `-execdir` is used intentionally in OP. The command worked here when issued in the directory containing the files.

Answer (score 2):

About your errors:

> find: The relative path `~/program_files/internet/SSH_tunneling/' is  included in the PATH environment variable, which is insecure in combination with the -execdir action of find.  Please remove that entry from $PATH

You have `~/program_files/internet/SSH_tunneling/` in your `$PATH`. That's a literal `~`. That does *not* mean your *home directory*. Instead, that means the *relative path* `~/program_files/internet/SSH_tunneling/`, that is `SSH_tunneling` inside `internet` inside `program_files` inside the `~` directory inside the current directory.

`-execdir` doesn't like relative directories in `$PATH` because it does `chdir()` into the directories it runs the commands to execute from. For instance, if when descending the directory tree, `find` finds a `gif` file in `./some-dir` that also contains a `~` directory, and there's a `./some-dir/~/program_files/internet/SSH_tunneling/basename`, then it may end up executing *that* `basename`.

You probably have a:

```
PATH="~/program_files/internet/SSH_tunneling/"
```

in your `~/.bash*` which should have been:

```
PATH=~/program_files/internet/SSH_tunneling/
```

or

```
PATH="$HOME/program_files/internet/SSH_tunneling"
```

> ```
>  $ find .  -regex ".*t\.gif" | xargs basename 
>  basename: extra operand ‘./f10_1t.gif’
> ```

`xargs` will run `basename` with as many arguments as possible. `basename` expects at most 2 arguments, the first one a path, the second a pattern. So your command doesn't make sense.

Also `xargs` by default, expects a blank (space, tab and possibly more depending on your locale and the `find` implementation) and newline (all of which may occur in file names) separated list on input with special handling of quotes, which is not the format output by `find`.

`find` will output something like:

```
./path/to/picture from "The End of the World".gif
```

Which `xargs` will understand as 3 different arguments: `./path/to/picture`, `from`, `The End of the World.gif`. `find` has no mode to output in the format expected by `xargs`, here:

```
./path/to/picture\ from\ \"The\ End\ of\ the\ World\".gif
```

or

```
'./path/to/picture from "The End of the World".gif'
```

Some `xargs` implementations do support a `-0` option though to handle a NUL delimited list instead of blank/newline+quotes one, and some `find` implementations have `-print0` predicate to output file names with that format (on those that don't, you can use `-exec printf '%s\0' {} +` instead).

So something like:

```
find .  -name "*t.gif" -print0 | xargs -r0 -I {} basename {} t.gif
```

which would be of little use for your overall goal. Instead you probably want something like:

```
find . -name '*t.gif' -type f -exec sh -c '
  for f do
    cp "${f%t.gif}.gif" "$f"
  done' sh {} +
```

Or with `zsh`:

```
autoload zmv # if not already in ~/.zshrc
zmv -C '(**/)(*)t.gif(#qD.)' '$1$2.gif'
```

Comment: Thanks. In "`xargs` expects a blank separated list on input with special handling of quotes", do you mean a white space by "blank"?  `find -print0` tells find to use the null character (\0) instead of whitespace as the output delimiter between pathnames found, so how does `-print0` create blank separated list? How does `-print0` achieve special handling of quotes?

Comment: @Tim, see edit, I hope it clarifies.